# HTML default selected option as default value of a vue data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I want the currently selected option in the dropdown to be the value of a vue data:

```
<select v-model="test">
     <option value="1" selected>A</option>
     ...
</select>
```

Not defined in vue instance with a default value

```
data: {
     test: '' // default should be the selected value in dropdown
}
```

I'm currently using laravel for displaying the options and rendering the html in the blade not in vue templates

UPDATE / MORE INFO:

The main idea is to load all html and data in laravel view but bind the dropdown's selected value (the selected is still based on laravel's loaded data) to a prop or data in vue.

```
<select v-model="item">
@foreach($item in $items)
     <option value="{{ $item }}" {{ $item == $some_data ? selected : '' }}>{{ $item }}</option>
     ...
@endforeach
</select>
```

And in my js file:

```
const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
         item: '',
     }
});
```

my goal is to bind the data to vue without using vue's default value of the data

Comment: From the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage): "v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. **You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.**"

Comment: Hi @LarsBeck, what if I am from an edit page and I want to load the existing value from an input. And the input is also binded to a vue data. Do I still need to declare the existing value in the js side?

Comment: Can you provide a viable code sample?

Comment: @LarsBeck I've added more info. Thanks

Comment: [This](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/select-box-using-external-data-in-vuejs-in-laravel-53#reply=301538) is what you want, you'll just have to pass the `$items` array and the current value (`$some_data`, which is `selected` in the linked example) to Vue and have the logic there